# Killed process starts again automatically!

Tags: bash, scripting, autostart

I've several Rasberry Pi with an app written in QT that automatically start at logon... the automatic start is made through the /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart file.
I've inserted in this file a rung "@bash /home/pi/Desktop/delayed_autostart &" to launch another file with a delayed start because I've to wait that the wifi connects to the router.
the other file contains:
sleep 20
/home/pi/Desktop/MYAPP

all works ok (the app is launched after 20 seconds) but........
when I need to upgrade the app I connect through VNC to the raspberry to kill the app (I open the task manager ad I kill MYAPP), I copy through SSHFTP the new app, but after 20 seconds again the app is relaunched! (°_°) so I've two identical task running... and if i kill it again is relaunched for 3 or 4 times, then stops to be relaunched...
Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try killing it by process name; use the below command:

```
 pkill -9 processname
```

Comment: same problem also killing with pkill

Comment: solved. the problem was that the delayed bash script remained opened in background, so starts the app over and over... modified killing bash adding after
sleep 20
/home/pi/Desktop/MYAPP
pkill bash